# Calling different versions of a template function depending on run-time argument

Tags: c++

I have several template functions whose template parameters always belong to the same enum, and would like to call the various instantiations based on the run-time value of a variable from that enum:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Number {One, Two};

template<Number N>
void g(int m) {
  std::cout << N << " " << m << std::endl;
}

int main() {

  auto n = Number::One;
  int m = 0;

  // I want to use this sort of construct for many different functions g
  if (n == Number::One) {
    g<Number::One>(m);
  }
  else if (n == Number::Two) {
    g<Number::Two>(m);
  }
}
```

Rather than write the branch every time, I would like to refactor it - here's my current attempt:

```
struct h {
  template<Number N>
  void operator()(int m) const {
    g<N>(m);
  }
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void split(F&& f, Number n, Args&&... args) {
  if (n == Number::One) {
    f.template operator()<Number::One>(args...);
  }
  else if (n == Number::Two) {
    f.template operator()<Number::Two>(args...);
  }
}

int main() {
  split(h{}, n, m);
}
```

Is this the cleanest way to achieve this? In particular, is it possible to rewrite `split` such that it will accept `g` directly, without me needing to wrap in struct `h`?

Comment: That's not possible, but isn't this what function *parameters* were designed for?

Comment: Templates are compile time constructs, you can't make them change behaviour at runtime. You should use a switch statement rather than lots of if statements.

Comment: Might be some inspiration based on Boost MPL: https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5142

Comment: For some motivation, imagine `Number` represents currencies, and I have a template class `template <Number N> P` representing prices in currency N - I would like a different type for each currency to catch as many errors at compile time as possible (e.g. I should not add prices in different currencies).
I'm trying to use the above sort of construct to e.g. take external input and immediately convert it into different types by currency for use internally.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without modifying `g`, because `g` cannot be represented in the type system. However, if you are willing to change `g` to e.g. a template struct with a static member function you could do it.

Comment: Given the motivation you've provided, are you already aware of this http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/OTHERS/scott_meyers/dimensions.pdf and similar concepts?

Comment: @AlanBirtles While the type of a specific instance of the class is not known until runtime the set of all possible combinations of template parameters should be known at compile-time and loops can be generated for each one. Boost MPL can certainly generate code to iterate over a set of types like this, using boost::mpl::for_each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap your function in *something*, but we can use a lambda instead of a class.

**If your enum values are contiguous**, use this:

(The code below relies on contiguous enum values. It allows us to use an array of function pointers for fast dispatch. If your enum is not contiguous, read below.)

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <utility>    

enum Number {One, Two, NumberCount};

template <Number N> void g(int m)
{
    std::cout << N << " " << m << std::endl;
}

template <typename L, std::size_t ...I>
const auto &split_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, L lambda)
{
    static decltype(lambda(std::integral_constant<Number, One>{})) array[] =
    {lambda(std::integral_constant<Number, Number(I)>{})...};
    return array;
}
template <typename L, typename ...P> void split(L lambda, Number n, P &&... p)
{
    split_impl(std::make_index_sequence<NumberCount>{}, lambda)[n](std::forward<P>(p)...);
}

int main()
{
    auto wrapped_g = [](auto i){return g<i.value>;};
    split(wrapped_g, One, 42);
}
```

**If your enum values are NOT contiguous**, use this:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <utility>    

enum Number {One, Two};

template <Number N> void g(int m)
{
    std::cout << N << " " << m << std::endl;
}

template <Number ...I, typename L> auto split_impl(L lambda, Number n)
{
    decltype(lambda(std::integral_constant<Number, One>{})) ret = 0;
    ((I == n ? (ret = lambda(std::integral_constant<Number, Number(I)>{}), 0) : 1) && ...);
    return ret;
}
template <typename L, typename ...P> void split(L lambda, Number n, P &&... p)
{
    split_impl<One, Two>(lambda, n)(std::forward<P>(p)...);
    //         ^~~~~~~~
    // List all your enum values here
}

int main()
{
    auto wrapped_g = [](auto i){return g<i.value>;};
    split(wrapped_g, One, 42);
}
```

---

P.S. I used `std::size_t` and `std::index_sequence` for simplicity. If you want robustness, you should use `std::integral_sequence<std::underlying_type_t<MyEnum>>`.

Answer (score 2):

From the first example

```
#include <iostream>

enum Number {One, Two};

template<Number N>
void g(int m) {
  std::cout << N << " " << m << std::endl;
}

int main() {

  auto n = Number::One;
  int m = 0;

  // I want to use this sort of construct for many different functions g
  if (n == Number::One) {
    g<Number::One>(m);
  }
  else if (n == Number::Two) {
    g<Number::Two>(m);
  }
}
```

I assume that you essentially want to dispatch to the template specializations `g<N>` depending on a runtime value `n`. So essentially you want to replace hand-written `if-else`-cascades or a switches with some centralized dispatch logic.

[The following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/blsWoAYwzp3chHTh) iterates over the enum values and calls the function `g<N>` matching the function parameter `m`. It does only work if the enum is consecutive and defines an end value for the iteration. This at least centralizes the dispatch, and if the enum is modified, the dispatch will work automatically.

```
 #include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum class Number {One, Two, Three, MAX};

template<Number N>
void g(int m) {
  std::cout << static_cast<int>(N) << " " << m << std::endl;
}

template<Number N>
struct Dispatch {
    void call(Number n, int m) {
        if (N == n) {
            g<N>(m);
        } else if (N != Number::MAX) {
            Dispatch< static_cast<Number>(static_cast<int>(N)+1) > next;
            next.call(n, m);
        } 
    }
};

template<>
struct Dispatch<Number::MAX> {
    void call(Number, int) {
        throw "Ohje";
    }
};

void dispatch(Number n, int m) {
    Dispatch<Number::One> d;
    d.call(n, m);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << argc << std::endl;
    dispatch(static_cast<Number>(argc-2), 42);
    return 0;
}
```

[You can further generalize the code to use it with different functions for `g`.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DAYlZfQQ2bP5I9lc) I wrapped the function call into helper structs to represent the free function `g<N>`. We can then pass the function to call if `N` and `m` match to `d

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

enum class Number {One, Two, Three, MAX};

template<Number N>
void g(int m) {
  std::cout << "g" << static_cast<int>(N) << " " << m << std::endl;
}

template<Number N> struct  S {
    void operator()(int m) {
        std::cout << "S" << std::endl;
        g<N>(m);
    }
};

template<Number N> struct  G {
    void operator()(int m) {
        std::cout << "G" << std::endl;
        g<N>(m);
    }
};

template<template<Number> typename C, Number N>
struct Dispatch {
    void call(Number n, int m) {
        if (N == n) {
            C<N> c;
            c(m);
        } else if (N != Number::MAX) {
            Dispatch< C, static_cast<Number>(static_cast<int>(N)+1) > next;
            next.call(n,m);
        } 
    }
};

template<template<Number> typename C>
struct Dispatch<C, Number::MAX> {
    void call(Number, int) {
        throw "Ohje";
    }
};

template<template<Number> typename C>
void dispatch(Number n, int m) {
    Dispatch<C, Number::One> d;
    d.call(n,m);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << argc << std::endl;
    dispatch<S>(static_cast<Number>(argc-2), 42);
    dispatch<G>(static_cast<Number>(argc-2), 23);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked if it's possible *without* wrapping `g`. Also, your code does something very different than OP's code.

Comment: @DDrmmr I've changed the code a little to IMHO be equivalent to the first example in the question. Depending on a runtime value `n`, a function `g<N>(m)` is called where `n == static_cast<int>(N)`. I also don't think that wrapping `g` is excluded in the question. You are also creating a wrapper in your answer. My code is not that different from your code. It only uses template recursion to generate what you are doing with a `switch`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with some modifications to the way `g` is defined.
In particular, I don't think it's possible to represent a template function in the type system, but it is possible to represent a template class/struct. So, I changed `g` to a struct with a static member function.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Number { One, Two };

template <Number N>
struct g
{
  static void call(int m)
  {
    std::cout << N << " " << m << std::endl;
  }
};

template <template<Number> class F, class R = void>
struct Wrap
{
  template <class... Args>
  static R call(Number n, Args&&... args)
  {
    switch (n) {
      case One: return F<One>::call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      case Two: return F<Two>::call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto n = Number::One;
  int m = 0;

  Wrap<g>::call(n, m);
}
```